# Magnetostatic: integral form of magnetic torque of a hard ferromagnet in an external magnetic field

Tags: integration, magnetostatics

It seems very easy but I can't find the expression of a magnet of magnetization (magnetic moment density) $\vec{M}$ in an external field $\vec{B}$. I found in the Jackson Classical Electrodynamics the expression for the magnetic dipole only: $\vec{T} = \vec{\mu} \wedge \vec{B}$, with $\vec{\mu}$ the magnetic dipole moment.

For a well-defined volume magnet (or any magnetic body) it seems really natural to express the torque applied by the external field $\vec{B}$ by the magnet of magnetization $\vec{M}$ with a volume integral on the magnet:

$\vec{T} = \iiint \left( \vec{M} (\vec{r}) \wedge \vec{B} (\vec{r}) \right) d^3 r $

Is this expression correct? It seems logical (when you replace $\vec{M} = \delta(\vec{r}) \vec{\mu} $ it gives you dipole formula) but I can't find it in a reference text book.

My question remains also for magnetic energy and magnetic force of a magnet submitted to an external field $\vec{B}$:

$ E = \iiint \left( \vec{M} . \vec{B} \right) d^3 r $  and $ \vec{F} = -  \iiint \vec{\nabla} \left( \vec{M} . \vec{B}  \right) d^3 r$

What do you think? I spend several hours on it. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you assume that your “hard ferromagnet” has a uniform (M) which is not effected by the external field, then the total dipole moment is just M times the total volume, and that can be used to find the torque.  However, in a real bar magnet, the M is likely to diverge (or converge) near the poles (which will effect the total dipole moment), and it is also likely to be effected by the external field.  Either of these would require the use of your final equations, and could be difficult to implement.

Comment: Thank you for explanation, yes I assume it's a hard ferromagnet with a high coercitive field to change his magnetization.

Answer (score 0):

Your torque equation needs a term that expresses the inhomogeneity of the magnetic field:
$$\mathbf{T} = \int_{\mathcal{V}}d\mathcal{V}\big(\mathbf {r} \times \nabla (\mathbf {M} \cdot \mathbf{B}) + \mathbf {M} \times  \mathbf{B} \big)$$

The term $\delta \mathbf{M}  \cdot \mathbf{B}$ is the infinitesimal work needed to add $\delta \mathbf{M}$ magnetization. But this assumes that the material is a *rigid* body, otherwise you have to include additional *mechanical* (strain and torsion work and energy) terms in the form of

$$\delta \mathcal{W}_m = \delta \mathbf{M}  \cdot \mathbf{B} + \delta  \theta \cdot (\mathbf {M} \times  \mathbf{B}) + \delta \mathbf{r} \cdot(\mathbf {M} \cdot \nabla \mathbf{B}) $$

For a rigid body, the elementary displacement and rotation within the body are zero, $ \delta \mathbf{r} =0$ and $ \delta \theta =0$, hence your formula but these will have to be included if magnetostriction is to be taken into account.

Comment: Yes I assume rigid body, no magnetostriction, but it gives me some informations thank you. The formula almost makes sence for me as I thought that the volumic force of an external field on the magnet was:

$\vec{f} = - \nabla ( \vec{M} . \vec{B}$

hence the torque on the magnet was:

$\vec{T} = \int_V d V \vec{r} \wedge \nabla (\vec{M} . \vec{B} )$

Comment: and maybe from this expression we can derive the $\vec{M} \wedge \vec{B}$ term? Anyway, thank you for your time

Comment: With your formulation I found a simplified expression of the torque, I guess, using vectorial identitie:

$ \vec{T} = \int_V d V \vec{M} \wedge \vec{B}  + \int_S  \left( \vec{M} . \vec{B} \right) \vec{r} \wedge \vec{d S} $

So logically I need to add the surface integral term to my calculations

Comment: Just for the others, the only good answer is my post above this one

Answer (score 0):

Ok so thanks to RW Bird and Hyportnex I would like to share a result for other readers. I found on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetization) the expression of the magnetization current defined from the magnetization $\vec{M}$ of the magnet:

$\vec{J_m} = \nabla \wedge \vec{M}$

So we can deduce the volumic Lorentz force (origin of magnetic torque and more generally Maxwell stress tensor) felt by the magnet in an external field $\vec{B}$:

$\vec{f} = \vec{J_m} \wedge \vec{B} = (\nabla \wedge \vec{M}) \wedge \vec{B} $

This expression can be rewrited in terms of material derivatives using identity:

$\nabla ( \vec{M} . \vec{B} ) = (\vec{M} . \nabla) \vec{B} + (\vec{B} . \nabla) \vec{M} + \vec{M} \wedge (\nabla \wedge \vec{B} ) + \vec{B} \wedge (\nabla \wedge \vec{M} )  $

and the torque is:

$\vec{T} = \int_V dV \vec{r} \wedge \vec{f} $

And I found that the expression $ \int_V dV \vec{M} \wedge \vec{B} $
does not exist. The expression $\vec{\mu} \wedge \vec{B}$ is true for a dipole in a constant magnetic field.